# Trigger the jQuery animate with live()

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-animate

I have a jQuery animation that is not working. I think the porblem comes from the parts that are the dynamic elements.

Is it possible to call the `live()` method with `animate()`?

Here's what I've go so far:

```
$(".tls").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
```

Comment: need more codes please... how would like it to happen? when elements appear or click or hover or scroll? what?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/hSR7f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some kind of trigger for the animation?

The code line you supplied will run the animation whenever the code line is reached in the code - what it seems you want, is to bind an animation to an element, and execute it later.

Try, for example,

```
$('.tls').on('click', function(ev) { 
    $(this).animate({left: '-=50px'}, 'slow'}); 
    // Add any necessary event handling here, for example
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: how does this x-fer to `delegate` or `on` since `live` is deprecated?

Comment: @tq: According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/), one should use `.on()` as a replacement for `.live()`. I've updated my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

LiveQuery is pretty good for dealing with dynamic elements.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the live call? Maybe you should use delegate instead: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Needed live and animate without an trigger. I wrote a little work around. I fixed it with a recursive function. Here is my example:

```
    $("#drops").html('<div class="drop-item item"></div>');

    adddrop();

    function adddrop() {
        $(".drop-item").animate({
            top: "+=90%"
        },2500,"easeInQuad", function() {
            if (parseInt($(".drop-item").css('left')) == parseInt($("#paddle").css('left'))) 
            {
                $("#drops").html('<div class="drop-item item"></div>');

                adddrop();
            } 
            else
            {
                alert('fail');
            } 
        });
    }
```

Hope I could help.